# how does the Completely Fair Scheduler (CFS) work in Android

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, android-source

I am trying to get a better understanding on ANDROID CFS. I have some doubt on scheduler's behavior.

*The difference between Android scheduler and Linux scheduler Scheduler — 5 files — The Android kernel also contains slight changes to the CPU process scheduler and time-keeping algorithms. We don’t know the history of these changes, and the impact was not evident based on a cursory examination.*

Do you know which are this files?

If I understand, Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT or Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND are 'nice' value. How does Android convert 'nice' value in 'timeslice'?

What is the initial value of 'virtual runtime' in Android and how to calculate?

In Android, is 'cgroups' use to define scheduling classes? The following application states: (i) Foreground process - Critical priority; (ii) Visible process and Service process - High priority; (iii) Background process and Empty process - Low priority; are three scheduling classes ?